# How to convert string expression to boolean in c++?

Tags: c++

How can I convert the string "a > b" to bool?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float condition(float a, float b)
    {
        bool cond;
        /*
        i'd like to see a function converting string "a > b" to bool
        */
        return cond
    }

int main()
{
    if (condition(7, 6))
       {
        cout << "a > b";
       }
}
```

In Python, I can do it like this:

```py
def condition(a, b):
    cond = f'{a} > {b}'
    return cond

if eval(condition(7, 6)):
    print('a > b')
```

Comment: You need to parse the input string and then evaluate it.

Comment: There's no function to evaluate expressions from strings like that in c++. You'll need to write an interpreter, or integrate one to do that.

Comment: First of all, *why* do you need to do this? What is the *original* problem this is supposed to solve? And while it's possible to interpret strings in Python using the `eval` function (because Python is an *interpreted* language) doesn't mean it's usually a good idea.

Comment: Python is [Interpreter](https://www.guru99.com/difference-compiler-vs-interpreter.html) while c++ is Compiler language. it accordingly can't evaluate expression at runtime, you probably have to parse and evaluate it by yourself

Comment: Your question needs more text. If I go with just what is written as text (*"How can I convert the string "a > b" to bool?"*), one answer is to call `empty()` on the string. Perfectly legit way to convert a string to `bool`, and equivalent to what is done in some languages. But not what you want, indicating that you did not use enough words to describe your situation. You don't want merely to convert to `bool`, but to **evaluate** the string. Please mention that, along with any restrictions you have in mind. (E.g. Do you have a "conversion" in mind for the string `"MIkhail"`?)

Comment: Also, your code does not match your text. At no point does your code (neither C++ nor Python) attempt to do anything with the string `"a > b"` other than print it out (note that `'{a} > {b}'` is not `'a > b'`). Your code demonstrates a rather convoluted approach to implementing `bool greater(float a, float b) { return a > b; }` since the comparison (`>`) is not an input to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you can utilize lambda functions to achieve something similar:

```
#include <iostream>

using CmpFunc = bool(float, float);

CmpFunc* condition(char op) {
  switch (op) {
    case '>':
      return [](float a, float b) { return a > b; };
    case '<':
      return [](float a, float b) { return a < b; };
    case '=':
      return [](float a, float b) { return a == b; };
    default:
      return [](float a, float b) { return false; };
  }
}

int main() {
  auto const cmp = condition('>');
  if (cmp(7, 6)) {
    std::cout << "a > b";
  }
}
```